# custom view in android using data binding

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview, android-viewmodel

Android developers, lend me your expertise! I have an app with six cards, each containing an icon image view, a title, and a data view model. I'm currently using a view model to represent the data for each card.

However, I want to handle each of the six cards separately, rather than having them all in one fragment. I don't want to use a RecyclerView or a List, and I'm looking for creative solutions.

What's the best approach to handle user interactions on each card individually, such as clicking on the icon or title? Should I create a separate fragment for each card, or is there a better way to do this?

I'd love to hear your suggestions and see some sample code if possible. Let's put our heads together and find a solution to this problem!